# Core plot x-axis labels are not shown

Tags: iphone, core-plot

This is my code. X-Axis labels are not shown. I am using core plot.

```
scatterGraph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
CPTheme *theme = nil;
[scatterGraph applyTheme:theme];
hostView.hostedGraph = scatterGraph;
hostView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
hostView.collapsesLayers = NO;

scatterGraph.paddingTop = 25.0;
scatterGraph.paddingRight = 25.0;
scatterGraph.paddingLeft = 25.0;
scatterGraph.paddingBottom = 25;
scatterGraph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
CPXYPlotSpace *scatterPlot = (CPXYPlotSpace *) scatterGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
scatterPlot.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPDecimalFromInt(yCount)];
float xx = [self findMax:LivePriceFeedArray] - [self findMin:LivePriceFeedArray]+1.0;
scatterPlot.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat([self findMin:LivePriceFeedArray]-0.5) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(xx)];

CPXYAxisSet *axisSet =(CPXYAxisSet *) scatterGraph.axisSet;
CPXYAxis *xAxis = axisSet.xAxis;
axisSet.delegate = self;
xAxis.title = @"Days";
xAxis.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(4.0f);
xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f);
xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromFloat(5.0f);
xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

NSUInteger labelLocation = 0;
NSMutableArray *customArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[xAxisLabels count]];
for (NSNumber *i in customLocations) {
    CPAxisLabel *iLabel = [[CPAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[xAxisLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation++] textStyle:xAxis.labelTextStyle];
    iLabel.tickLocation = [i decimalValue];
    [customArray addObject:iLabel];
    [iLabel release];
}

xAxis.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customArray];
xAxis.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:customLocations ];
CPLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
xAxis.majorGridLineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];

CPXYAxis *yAxis = axisSet.yAxis;
yAxis.title = @"Sales Target";
yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromFloat(1.0f);
yAxis.labelOffset = -5.0f;
yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f);
CPScatterPlot *graphPlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc]init] autorelease];
CPMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [[graphPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 3.0f;
lineStyle.lineColor =  [CPColor whiteColor];
graphPlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
graphPlot.dataSource = self;
[scatterGraph addPlot:graphPlot];
graphPlot.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
CPLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
xAxis.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
yAxis.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
yAxis.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
```

Why are the x-axis labels not shown?

Comment: Not sure about this but try and adjust the padding left of your graph ...  **scatterGraph.paddingLeft = 25.0;** just try and adjust

Comment: Nopes that is not working with my case... I tried with padding 100 also. Labels are not displayed... :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the issue. There was a problem with orthogonal coordinates.

I solved it like this:

> `scatterPlot.yRange = [CPPlotRange
>   plotRangeWithLocation:
>   CPDecimalFromFloat (min)
>   length:CPDecimalFromFloat(xx)];`
>   `xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal =
>   CPDecimalFromFloat(min);`

Here plotRangeWithLocation for y-axis and orthogonalCoordinateDecimal for x-axis should be the same.

Thanks for the help, Krishnabhadra :)

Comment: I don't know who down voted you. But you must frame a question better. Just a title and a bunch of code won't please the community. A question should warrant an answer.

Comment: Also it is good that you found your problem yourself (which is always good than someone helping you). You posted an answer, that means you value the community. Then you should provide more info on your answer so that it can help others. *There was a problem with orthogonal coordinates* is not enough information..

Comment: Also if you update the answer, do accept your answer..You can accept your own answer..That makes others know you have found a solution to a problem..