# Power BI Line chart Fix the X Axis label so that only day and month are shown

Tags: date, powerbi, linechart

My problem is: I'm strugling with Power bi trying to correct a default behaviour of the line chart. In this case when I try to filter my data for periods of 2 to 5 days the hours of the day appear in the X axis. Like I show in the image below. In my date hierarchy I have specified my date column with the format (dd/mm/yyyy) and the column is of the type "date", but he hours of the day still appear.
[image]

How can I get rid of the hours of the day when I select only 2 to 5 days in the slicer of time??

What I've tried: I've tried to change the date column in my line chart visual so that only the month and the day appear but when a monthly period of days is selected the visual isn't able to show all the data at once and the user needs to scroll in the element, so it is not a solution. I've also tried to change the format of my date column but without sucess.

The desired result must show only the days without the hours of the day like the image bellow: [image]

Links I've followed but sadly didn't help:

[Power Bi Axis X and Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199353/power-bi-axis-x-and-y)

[Core plot x-axis labels are not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196469/core-plot-x-axis-labels-are-not-shown)

[In Power BI X-axis label, how to show only week starting day instead of all date series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59169034/in-power-bi-x-axis-label-how-to-show-only-week-starting-day-instead-of-all-date)

[Can Power BI add range selection to a Line Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822053/can-power-bi-add-range-selection-to-a-line-chart)